# Search Visibility setting is not saved

Tags: 2007, search

I am trying to turn on the search visibility for a site in Sharepoint 2007.

Unfortunately, after I click OK and then return to this page, it is still turned-off and of course the content is not visible by the search engine. There are not error messages too.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If yes you can try doing it using powershell or by writing console app.

Comment: I have already tried powershell to no avail.

The script runs fine when tested with other sites, but not for this one.